Importance of "__tablename__" in SQLAlchemy
I am following a tutorial for a React + Flask app where I have to make models in SQLAlchemy. One of which is a User model:
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True, unique=True, default=get_uuid)
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)

My question is why do I have to include __tablename__ in my model?
I tried to get rid of it but my API stops working. I am confused since all the other models I have ever made in SQLAlchemy have never included a __tablename__ property so why is it necessary for this one?

SQLAlchemy requires that __tablename__ is set on the model class. It's possible to set it using a method, which is what Flask-SQLAlchemy does. Whether this has anything to do with yor API not working is impossible to tell from the information provided.

If you're using Flask-SQLAlchemy, which generates table names, there's a mismatch between your class name User and tablename users (the 's').
